# Would a 'absolute nothingness' (Kabbalistic Ayin) be present in Brian Greene's Ultimate Multiverse?

Tags: physics, nonspherical-worlds

Want to try having Ultimate Multiverse as worldbuild background. But I wonder if it is compatible with Kabbalistic concepts or not.

And after reading through Brian Greene's Ultimate Multiverse about 'Universe which consists of Nothing', I'm kinda curious if  Kabbalistic Ayin/Ain would be 'present' in it or not (more info is in here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ayin_and_Yesh).

Short description of Ayin/Ain is that Ain is Absolutely "nothing". Not even boundlessness, not everything, not nothing, just "not". You can not say or think anything about Ain (any words and thoughts are limited), you can only keep silent about Ain.

'Universe' or maybe a 'being' consists of absolutely nothing. No information, no thoughts, no space, no time, no dimensions....

So... would Ain be containable by Ultimate MUltiverse?

Comment: That's like asking if 0, when used a placeholder, is a number.

Comment: I voted to put question on hold as "unclear" because it appears to ask us to comment on the viability of that which cannot be commented on. That's a pretty unclear question to me.

Comment: @SRM The question seems perfectly clear to me.  And the answer is we can't answer you because we can't comprehend the concepts by the definitions in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking if something undefinable and beyond human comprehension can be contained by something that we can comprehend?

Just logically I would say that's a big, **NO** or at the very least if we are incapable of understanding either we can make judgments about neither.

You've logic'd yourself into a situation where the answer is, *"That can't be answered"*